# C++ discard the leftover newline from input buffer issue

Tags: c++, newline, do-while

I am trying to get this assignment down for a c++ class.  I had issues with the do/while loop not working correctly and someone suggested adding the line cin.ignore(2,'\n'); in the InputData function under where the enter student name is being asked by the user.  That worked and the do/while is now working.  However, I'm not 100% sure how the cin.ignore(2,'\n'); works and I have an issue during the first go around where the first two characters of the "name" that the user inputs is getting discarded.  If I change that 2 to a 0 it it doesn't cut off the first two characters of the name but if the user enters 'y' they'd like to continue, the program skips the first question "Enter the name of the student".

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

FYI, I am super new to programming in general, especially c++.  Be nice please lol.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
   Student();
   ~Student();
   // Input all info of user
   void InputData();
   // Output class list
   void OutputData();
   // Reset class list
   void ResetClasses();
   Student& operator =(const Student& rightSide);

private:
    string name;
    string stuName;
    int numbClasses;
    string *classList;
};//end student class

//Initialize variables to empty and array to NULL
Student::Student() {
    numbClasses = 0;
    classList = NULL;
    name = "";
}//end variable initialization

//Frees up any memory allocated to array.
Student::~Student() {
    if (classList != NULL) {
    delete [ ] classList;
}//end if
}//end free memory

//Delete the class list
void Student::ResetClasses() {
    if (classList != NULL) {
       delete [] classList;
       classList = NULL;
    }//end if block
    numbClasses = 0;
}//end reset classes
```

Here is where the line cin.ignore(2,'\n'); is located

```
// Inputs info from user.
void Student::InputData() {

int i;
// Reset the class list in case method is called again and array isn't cleared
ResetClasses();

cout << "Enter student name." << endl;
//Discards the leftover newline from input buffer
cin.ignore(2,'\n');
getline(cin, name);


cout << "Enter number of classes." << endl;
cin >> numbClasses;
//Discards the leftover newline from input buffer
cin.ignore(2,'\n');
if (numbClasses > 0) {
    // Construct array big enough to hold # of classes
    classList = new string[numbClasses];
    // Loop through the # classes, input name of each one into array
    for (i = 0; i < numbClasses; i++) {
        cout << "Enter name of class " << (i+1) << endl;
        getline(cin, classList[i]);
    }//end for loop
}//end if block
cout << endl;
}//end input data
```

Output data

```
//Output info entered by user.
void Student::OutputData() {

int i;
cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
cout << "Number of classes: " << numbClasses << endl;
for (i=0; i<numbClasses; i++) {
    cout << "  Class " << (i+1) << ":" << classList[i] << endl;
}//end for loop
cout << endl;
}//end Output data

//overload this operator so there aren't two references to same class list.
Student& Student::operator =(const Student& rightSide) {

int i;
// Erase list of classes
ResetClasses();
name = rightSide.name;
numbClasses = rightSide.numbClasses;

// Copy the list of classes
if (numbClasses > 0) {
    classList = new string[numbClasses];
    for (i=0; i<numbClasses; i++) {
        classList[i] = rightSide.classList[i];
    }//end for loop
}//end if block
return *this;
}//end overload
```

Main, where the do/while loop is located.

```
// main function
int main() {

    char choice;
    //Do/While loop to ask user if they'd like to continue or end program.
do {
    // Test code with two student classes
    Student s1, s2;
    // Input for s1
    s1.InputData();
    cout << "Student 1's data:" << endl;
    // Output for s1
    s1.OutputData();
    cout << endl;

    s2 = s1;
    cout << "Student 2's info after assignment from student 1:" << endl;
    // Should output same info as student 1
    s2.OutputData();

    s1.ResetClasses();
    cout << "Student 1's info after the reset:" << endl;
    // Should have no classes
    s1.OutputData();

    cout << "Student 2's info, should still have original classes:" << endl;
    // Should still have original classes
    s2.OutputData();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Would you like to continue? y/n" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

} while(choice == 'y'); //end do/while
return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/ and next time please use a MCVE. Please.

Comment: The MCVE is for your sake as much as ours. You should always try to develop new functionality *in isolation*, writing the smallest, simplest program that will exercise the technique you're trying to master (such as `getline(cin, ...)`). Once it works perfectly, you can incorporate it into something larger.

Comment: Just use `std::cin.ignore();` instead of specifying the size and the character.. it'll work.

Comment: Hey Brandon, thanks for the help.  It's still cutting off one character though.  Beta/Chantola, I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: Use `std::cin.ignore()` just before the end of the `do-while` loop, right after `cin >> choice;` Remove the first call to `std::cin.ignore()` from `InputData()`.

Comment: Sahu & Brandon, THANK YOU!  You guys are awesome!  Beta/Chantola, I can understand the frustration with peoples questions sometimes  but, you guys took more time to complain then help.  I'm SUPER new to this, meaning only 5 one hour classes in c++.  So when you post a link and expect me to magically find the answer in there...it kinda sucks.  Isn't the point of Stack to help other people out?  I apologize if I misunderstood your comments but i've been working on this for days, I've searched high & low for the answer & it seemed to me like you were suggesting I didn't do enough on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you **remove** all the `cin.ignore(2,'\n');` statements and instead skip the whitespace (spaces and returns) immediately before you use `std::getline()`. You can do this with the `std::ws` manipulator: **see:** [std::ws](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/ws/)

So your `std::getline()` statements become:

```
getline(cin >> std::ws, name); // NOTE: >> std::ws skips whitespace
```

**So like this:**

```
// Inputs info from user.
void Student::InputData() {

int i;
// Reset the class list in case method is called again and array isn't cleared
ResetClasses();

cout << "Enter student name." << endl;
//Discards the leftover newline from input buffer
//cin.ignore(2,'\n');
getline(cin >> std::ws, name); // NOTE: >> std::ws skips whitespace

cout << "Enter number of classes." << endl;
cin >> numbClasses;
//Discards the leftover newline from input buffer
//cin.ignore(2,'\n');
if (numbClasses > 0) {
    // Construct array big enough to hold # of classes
    classList = new string[numbClasses];
    // Loop through the # classes, input name of each one into array
    for (i = 0; i < numbClasses; i++) {
        cout << "Enter name of class " << (i+1) << endl;
        getline(cin >> std::ws, classList[i]); // NOTE: >> std::ws skips whitespace
    }//end for loop
}//end if block
cout << endl;
}//end input data
```

Comment: Thanks Galik!  I'm going to check that out.  It looks more efficient then what I have now.

Comment: Hey Galik, so I wouldn't need to add the std::ws under numbClasses as well?

Comment: @user3862586 Not sure what you mean by "under" (after? before?) but you shouldn't need it anywhere else. Your code seems to work fine for me with the changes I propose.